# Who is this character in "Avengers: Endgame"?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, character-identification, avengers-endgame

At the end of *Avengers: Endgame* when all the super heroes are fighting Thanos and this army, there is a brief exchange between Thanos and some woman that (paraphrasing from memory) goes something like:

> Thanos: I don't know who you are
>
> Woman: But you will

So who is this woman? And what are the connotations of her reply?

Comment: It feels like it is a remark from Captain Karen.

Comment: I’ve only seen it once, and that was weeks ago, but wasn’t it Captain Marvel?

Comment: @Darren It didn't seem to be Marvel, but it was so brief that I never got a good impression.  Still the temporal context makes it strange

Comment: I think that was actually Wanda Maximoff, just after she came back from being dusted and told Thanos that he took everything from her.

Comment: @PeterM have you seen *Avengers: Infinity War*?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite oh that’s it, I remember now. I knew it was someone obvious.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Yes I have.. and??

Comment: @PeterM Wanda’s a fairly prominent character in *Infinity War*. We see her in Glasgow with Vision, when they’re attacked by two of Thanos’ minions and saved by Captain America and friends. Near the end of the movie she destroys the Mind Stone in Vision’s head, before Thanos turns time back and takes it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The woman in question is Wanda Maximoff, aka Scarlet Witch, who was introduced (properly) in the Marvel Cinematic Universe in *Avengers: Age of Ultron*, along with her brother Quicksilver.

As for her exchange with Thanos and its connotations.

> Thanos: I don't even know who you are.

This is true. This "2014 Thanos" has never met Wanda, contrary to his 2018 self.

> Wanda: But you will.

This is related to the events of *Avengers: Infinity War*. See, Wanda's in love with Vision, a highly advanced android whose existence is strongly based on the Mind Stone, that Thanos absolutely needed to complete his Infinity Gauntlet. Thus, not only did he take the Stone, killing Wanda's lover, he did so after rewinding time, because remember, [Wanda had previously destroyed the Stone, *killing her own lover*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eyhz6MImCvA). And then got snapped out of existence.

Once again, this is (an earlier version of) the guy who made her kill her lover, had him killed *again*, and made her disappear.

So **he will** come to know who she is. Not just "2018 Thanos" (if Wanda has even realized that wasn't the Thanos she knew), but **he will know who she is**, in like, the ten seconds to come, because she'll unleash all the power she's got on his face.

And that nearly works, since Thanos has no choice but to order his ship to rain fire on the whole battlefield to escape Wanda's wrath.